# DB implicitly converts from INT to NVARCHAR(128) warning

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

On my Azure SQL database I get a warning in 'Actual Execution Plan' in SQL Server Management Studio whenever I select.

[image: SSMS warning]

It is due to the following 'where' in my row level security.

```
WHERE (@GROUP_ID = USER_NAME()) OR (IS_MEMBER('ReadOrWriteAll') = 1)
```

GROUP_ID is an int that's being compared to USER_NAME() which returns a NVARCHAR(128).

I've tried converting GROUP_ID into a NVARCHAR, but the warning remains. 
I've tried using str(@GROUP_ID) and convert(@GROUP_ID).

Comment: `CAST(@GROUP_ID as nvarchar(128))`

Comment: If `@GROUP_ID` is an `INT`, it doesn't contain a user name unless you're on the set of *The Prisoner*. Conversion issues aside, why do you think the expression `@GROUP_ID = USER_NAME()` is even meaningful?

Comment: Apart from the fact that I'd be very surprised if `USER_NAME()` returns a number -- what kind of company do you work in ?!?? --, if you really want to get rid of the (implicit) conversion inside the query, then `DECLARE` a `@GROUP_SID` variable as an `nvarchar(128)` (which indeed is what `USER_NAME()` returns although the documentation says otherwise, strange) upfront and store `@GROUP_ID` in it. In the `WHERE` you then use `@GROUP_SID` and all should be well...

Comment: It makes no difference @ZoharPeled.

Comment: @JeroenMostert and deroby a GROUP_ID represents the client who created the row, and it's used as filter in row level security. If the GROUP_ID is 1234 then user named "1234" is made.
These users are used by an app to access the db on behalf of the users and display their data to them. 'Admin' logins have regular names, so GROUP_ID = USER_NAME() is meaningful, when it's meant to be.